# Mapbox: How to get lat/lng value into input field and place a marker by mouse clicking on the map?

Tags: javascript, forms, mapbox

I tried the following code to place a marker on the included Mapbox-map with a mouse click on the map and write the latitude/longitude values from this marker into the two input-fields below the map:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        #addmap {
            position: abolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='addmap'></div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PLACEHOLDER_FOR_MAPBOX_TOKEN';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'addmap',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
        });
        function onClick(event){
            document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latlng.lat;
            document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latlng.lng;
            var group = L.featureGroup();
            group.id = 'group';
            var p_base = L.circleMarker([event.latlng.lat ,event.latlng.lng], {
                color: '#fff',
                fillColor: '#6a97cb',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                weight: 1,
                radius: 6
            }).addTo(group);
            map.addLayer(group);
        }

        </script>
        <input id='lat' name='lat' type='text' />
        <input id='lng' name='lng' type='text' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, neither placing the marker on the map nor writing its coordinates into the input fields work when clicking on the map. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific error you are seeing? I'm not sure from looking at the code where `L` is coming from? Here's a very simple example you could start from: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-a-marker/

Comment: No error message - just nothing happens when you click on the map. No marker appears, no coordinates are written in the input fields. So the onClick(event) seems not to work, but I have no clue why.

Comment: Ah I see the issue - you need to register the `onClick` function as an event listener to the map. Something like ```let el = document.getElementById(id-of-map-element-here); el.addEventListener('click', onClick);``` Right now you have a function named "onClick" but nothing ever calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens when you click on the map because you haven't registered your `onClick` function as a "click" event listener.

Try the following:

```
let mapEl = document.getElementById('addmap');
mapEl.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

Then, when you click on the map element, it will trigger your `onClick` event listener.

Comment: Thank you you very much! Basically I was not calling the function anywhere, right? Unfortunately it still doesn't work when adding the following lines to the code above either before or after the function:

`let mapEl = document.getElementById(map);
mapEl.addEventListener('click', onClick);`

Comment: sorry I didn't see you inserted the map into that div in your original code. I updated my answer with the correct id. instead of `map` it should be `addmap`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried that out, as it was my first guess as well - but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  //marker.setLngLat(e.lngLat);
  var lat = e.lngLat.wrap().lat;
  var lng = e.lngLat.wrap().lng;
   $("input#latbox").val(lat);
   $("input#lngbox").val(lng);
});
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).